# Why python script stops executing the statement of loop but the process itself is alive?

Tags: ssh, python, opencv

i am running face recognition python script on Ubutnu 18.04 as a daemon  which takes pictures from another server with ssh request and performs operations on them .
i have this code in python script which is always running but the statement of while loop stops being executed .
the process itself is alive

```
While true:
 ssh request to another server to recieve pictures 
 time.sleep(1)
```

i check the directory of another server and the pictures are present there

Comment: Stuck on a password prompt? How do you do the SSH login?

Comment: i use rsync to get the images from another server with sshpass

Comment: The problem is likely somewhere in the "ssh request to another server to recieve pictures", so you have to copy the code here (remove actual node/user/passwords of course). You can also add a print statement before and after, to make sure this is the part that blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question, you're running a thread as a daemon. Python threads are inherently non-deamon and this is best left off. Daemons do not terminate when the program is explicitly terminated, when you terminate the program you must join the Daemon thread back to its parent by calling .join().

Also Python can't use threads because of the GIL, so it is better to use the multiprocessing package and to implement Processes instead of Threads.

But you need to give us more code to truly answer your question.

```
thread = Thread(target=clientThread, args=(connection, client_address, history))
        try:
            print('Starting Thread for: ', client_address)
            thread.start()


def clientThread (connection, client_address, history):  
    while True:                        
         data = connection.recv(512).decode('utf8')
         dataParser(connection, client_address,history, data)
```